# Ensuring that threads are returned in the order they were created

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multiprocessing

I have a simply problem that I am hoping someone here can help me with.  I have a function that is called as a series of thread via a for loop.  the array output is stored to a `Queue` and retrieved in the main program.  The threading works perfect, unfortunately the arrays of data are being returned in a different order than they were called.  I am enclosing a pseudo code example in this question.  Is there some thread lock mechanism that will allow the threads to be created and run in parallel, but returned in the order they were created.

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def Thread_Func(container1,container2,container3,iterable,more_parameters, \
                Thread):
    Array1 = np.array([]); Array2 = np.array([])
    for i in range(len(iterable)):
        Array1 = np.append(some_operation)
        Array2 = np.append(some_other_operation)
    container1.put(Array1)
    container2.put(Array2)
    container3.put(Thread)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    container1 = Queue()
    container2 = Queue()
    container3 = Queue()
    Thread = 1
    for index in range(Number_of_Threads):
        p = Process(target=Thread_Func,args=(container1,container2,container3, \
                    iterable,more_parameters))
        Thread = Thread + 1
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()

    Array1       = np.array([])
    Array2       = np.array([])
    Thread_Array = np.array([])
    for index in range(Number_of_Threads)
        Array1 = np.append(Array1,container1.get())
        Array2 = np.append(Array2,container2.get())
        Thread_Array = np.append(Thread_Array,container3.get())
    p.join()

    print (Array1)
    print (Array2)
    print (Thread_Array)
```

It is pretty obvious after looking at the printout of `Array1` that the threads were returned out of order, but when I look at `Thread_Array` after running two threads I see the `[2. 1.]`, when I should see `[1. 2.]`.  Is there something I can do to ensure that the threads are returned in the proper order?

Comment: Why order of thread num is important here ? I guess not, because it may return back to single thread way if we suppose the first thread run is very long, and other threads have to wait for it... What about reorder in the thread num list

Comment: Build an example that actually runs.  `numpy` can be completely eliminated from the equation and the example much simplified.  Why isn't `Thread` being passed in Process creation?

Comment: And please explain WHY you're trying to do this.

Comment: You could use only one Queue, and `.put((Thread,Array1,Array2))`.  Being threads, there is no guarantee the three puts will happen without context switch.  Then use Thread to order the results from the Queue, if it matters.

Comment: Assuming one thread I am passing an array of data in this case beam position and am trying to solve for the stress at each beam position, which will then be plotted.  If I divide the array of beam locations into three arrays and create a thread for each array, I would like to be able to solve for the stress at each point.  If the arrays are returned out of order and appended that way, I can not create a continuous plot, which is why I need them returned in the order they were called.

Comment: @ Mark Tolonen, minus appending them to a Tuple, that is the solution I have come to, but am hoping there is a more elegant solution that will allow for them to be returned in the correct order.

Comment: They are threads (well, Processes).  They can finish in any order. With three Queues, even the order of the items in the Queues can be different.  One Queue solves that.  The tuple keeps the results for a single thread bundled together, but still need to sort the results by Thread number.  You could pass some indexed container and store the results at the index indicated by Thread if you want.

Answer (score 0):

A multiprocessing.Pool sounds like what you need.  The default is to create a pool equal to the number of processors in the system.  You can submit work and store the future result in an array in the order submitted, then get the results in the order needed.

Example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import random

# Use a simple list of numbers for work
work = list(range(100))

# Run jobs in size of chunk.
chunk = 10

random.seed(time.time())

# This work is so simple we'll sleep to simulate longer work calculations
# and the threads will finish in random order.
def worker(arr):
    time.sleep(random.randint(1,5)/20) # .05 to .25 seconds
    return [x*10 for x in arr]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    results = []

    # Break the work into chunks, and submit jobs to run asynchronously.
    # The callback will print the index of the job as it finishes.
    for i in range(0,len(work),chunk):
        results.append(pool.apply_async(
            worker,
            args=(work[i:i+chunk],),
            callback=lambda x,i=i:print(i)))

    # Fetch the results in the order submitted.
    for result in results:
        print(result.get())
```

Observe that the threads finished out-of-order.  Fetching the first result stalled until it was complete, then the results are printed in order up to the jobs that have finished.  Then it stalled again waiting for the 50-range to finish.

Output:

```
10
30
20
40
0
[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
[100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190]
[200, 210, 220, 230, 240, 250, 260, 270, 280, 290]
[300, 310, 320, 330, 340, 350, 360, 370, 380, 390]
[400, 410, 420, 430, 440, 450, 460, 470, 480, 490]
80
90
70
60
50
[500, 510, 520, 530, 540, 550, 560, 570, 580, 590]
[600, 610, 620, 630, 640, 650, 660, 670, 680, 690]
[700, 710, 720, 730, 740, 750, 760, 770, 780, 790]
[800, 810, 820, 830, 840, 850, 860, 870, 880, 890]
[900, 910, 920, 930, 940, 950, 960, 970, 980, 990]
```